# In django I have created field and added some entries to the field afte

Tags: django

In Django I have created a field named `pincode` and added some entries like 876786876, 8768768776.

After some time I added a unique argument but it showed some error so I removed the field from the model but still shows some error when running

```
python manage.py migrate
```

The error:

```
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: haystack
  Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, polls, auth, sessions
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
  Installing custom SQL...
  Installing indexes...
Running migrations:
  Applying polls.0007_auto_20141104_2055...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 160, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=options.get("fake", False))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 63, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(migration, fake=fake)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 97, in apply_migration
    migration.apply(project_state, schema_editor)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 107, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, project_state, new_state)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 139, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 473, in alter_field
    self._alter_field(model, old_field, new_field, old_type, new_type, old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 190, in _alter_field
    self._remake_table(model, alter_fields=[(old_field, new_field)])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 135, in _remake_table
    self.quote_name(model._meta.db_table),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 99, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 81, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 485, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: column pincode is not unique
```

Comment: What was the error exactly?

Comment: Did you migrate the database so that the field was actually changed at the database level?

Comment: yes I migrated actually I am new to django and databases

Answer (score 1):

It would appear you have duplicate fields in that column. The UNIQUE constraint can't be added until the data in the table already conforms to the constraint.

If you don't care about your data, just TRUNCATE or DROP the table. If you do care about the data, you'll need to identify the duplicated rows and ensure that the field in question is unique.

Answer (score -1):

I you don't mind, delete the file of your database (in case you're using SQLite) and syncdb again, sometimes migrating don't "delete" the table columns, if you dont want to loose your info try to dump it before into a json and load it after syncdb with loaddata